# OnTriggerEnter2D with TextMeshPro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change my text if b1 is triggered.

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using TMPro;
  public class Player_Start : MonoBehaviour
  {
    [SerializeField] public TextMeshProUGUI textTest;
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b1"))
         {
           textTest.text = "Now let's move the right leg up!";                 
           transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
           transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b2"))
       {
         transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(false);
         transform.GetChild(3).gameObject.SetActive(true);
       }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Player_Start.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Player_Start.cs:16)

Line 16 says:

```
textTest.text = "Now let's move the right leg up!";
```

Comment: Have you checked if the children that you are trying to access exist? It may be good to enclose them in conditional statements.

Comment: Without the textTest, the children worked out fine.

Comment: Well did you reference the `textTest`?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change:

`TextMeshProUGUI textTest`

to

`TMP_Text textTest`

(and then re-assign your tmp gameobject to the textTest variable on your script of course)

Otherwise that error often just means you forgot to assign something to that variable in the inspector.